# Dependency property taking an enum

Tags: wpf, enums, dependency-properties

I have defined a dependency property that uses an enum to update the background colour of a button. When it runs I get a "Default value type does not match type of property 'CurrentWarningLevel'" exception. The dependency property is as follows:

```
public enum WarningLevels
{
    wlError=0,
    wlWarning,
    wlInfo
};

public class WarningLevelButton : Button
{
    static WarningLevelButton()
    {
    }

    public WarningLevels CurrentWarningLevel
    {
        get { return (WarningLevels)GetValue(WarningLevelProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(WarningLevelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WarningLevelProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentWarningLevel", typeof(WarningLevels), typeof(WarningLevelButton), new PropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

I am trying to use the property as follows:

```
<Trigger Property="local:WarningLevelButton.CurrentWarningLevel" Value="wlError">
    <Setter TargetName="ButtonBody" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CtlRedBrush}" />
    <Setter TargetName="ButtonBody" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource CtlRedBrush}" />
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="local:WarningLevelButton.CurrentWarningLevel" Value="wlWarning">
    <Setter TargetName="ButtonBody" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GreyGradientBrush}" />
    <Setter TargetName="ButtonBody" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderBrush}" />
</Trigger>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)**
Because you can't cast `false(bool)` into `WarningLevels`.

Remember the first parameter of `PropertyMetadata` is your default value.

**2)** You propably will run into another problem. Your Trigger value

```
Value="wlError"
```

is a string, which can't be converted into an enum aswell, without a type converter. The easiest way to fix that is to extend your value:

```
<Trigger Property="local:WarningLevelButton.CurrentWarningLevel" >
    <Trigger.Value>
        <my:WarningLevels>wlError</my:WarningLevels>
    </Trigger.Value>
    <Setter TargetName="ButtonBody" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CtlRedBrush}" />
    <Setter TargetName="ButtonBody" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource CtlRedBrush}" />
</Trigger>
```

Comment: I question your second point. There is [type converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645047.aspx) support for [enums in general](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.enumconverter.aspx).